# Why do I enjoy low-mid level pain?

Tags: pain

For example, say if I have really dry elbows. They become cracked and begin to flay, yet I continue to rub them against various kinds of surfaces for the different sensations of pain. It hurts alot, and I've found myself experimenting with my pain threshold.

I have other small things like these which I do constantly in order to feel pain, and I *enjoy* it. What is the reason behind this?